# How to discern which anchor is in view with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a navigation tab that points to differenct sections of the page, identified by ids:

```
<section id="1"></section>
<section id="2"></section>
<section id="3"></section>
```

Then I link to the section in my navigation links:

```
<a href="#1"></a>
```

Now I would like to apply some custom styling to my navigation links when the corresponding section is displayed in the viewport of the browser.

Clicking the link adds the id to the end of the URL, but since I want to be able to apply the styling even if the user does not click any links, I feel that this is not a valid solution.

Is there a CSS property that I check for with javascript that tells me that a certain section is in view?

I am searching for a solution that will work with multiple screen sizes.

Comment: Look for 'jquery scroll spy'.

Comment: http://scrollnav.com/ -> this may be of use as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [scrollSpy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy) or something similar. The idea is to check which elements are within viewport and assign corresponding classes via js.

This can be easily done without any libraries as well:

1. Listen for scroll events on document
2. Run your calculation function (this should be [throttled](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/))
3. Select all nav items and check if they're in viewport (offsetTop + height)
4. Assign classes

Comment: The problem with this is that is requires a bootstrap nav component, and since I am not using bootstrap for the rest of my solution I feel this is overkill